# Unusual behavior of \\ in pmatrix environment

Tags: support, mathjax

I found an unusual behavior of pmatrix environment when editing a post.

Basically, when editing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037479/exponential-of-matrix) `$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&9 \cr -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$` renders correctly, but `$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&9 \\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$` does not. The only difference is that in one case I use `\cr` to make new line, in the other case I use `\\`.

As you can see, both versions render correctly here:
$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&9 \cr -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&9 \\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$.

However, here is screenshot showing what the matrix/question looked like when I used version with `\\` instead of `\cr`:

[image: screenshot of the matrix]

[image: screenshot of the post]

I don't think it's a big deal, but it I'm curious why the same code behaves differently in that question. And also it might be useful to know, in case something similar might manifest elsewhere.

**EDIT:** Now I am confused even more. At the moment the question renders ok with \ (at least I see it rendered correctly). But when I click on edit, the preview show the strange version with the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to that question contains the definition `$\def\\#1{\frac1{#1!}}$` which spills over to the preview, but not to the question. (Owing to the order of script execution, I assume).

Comment: [D'oh!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!). I searched whether there is `\newcommand` somewhere in the source. And `\def` simply did not occur to me. Based on this older post I would expect the same behavior in the question: [The scope of \newcommand is the entire page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page)

Comment: Quite a horrible incident. Almost as bad as someone redefining other core commands. Like integrals and sine stuff. Try it out... $\newcommand{\sin}{\text{Troll'd!}}\newcommand{\int}{\text{Ha ha }}\newcommand{\cos}{\text{ Fo' shizzle!}}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila As we all know, $\int \sin(x)\;dx = -\cos(x)$.  `:)`