# MathJax bug in tag wiki edit

Tags: bug, mathjax, tag-wikis, markdown-preview, editor

I have suggested an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1002912) on the tag wiki of [circulant-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circulant-matrices), based on a [related tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/hilbert-matrices/info) for [hilbert-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilbert-matrices).

While typing the code, I observed that `\\` is interpreted as `\` in the preview.  This gives incorrect output.

[image]

Comment: This seems similar to a bug I've reported in previewing edits from Review, [MathJax renders badly when editing from Review Queue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27195/mathjax-renders-badly-when-editing-from-review-queue).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the link.  It's sad that this bug remains there for nearly half a year.

Comment: See this [related post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/mathjax-preview-does-not-work-when-editing-from-review-or-when-editing-a-delete).