# Bug: Can't write matrices and newlines $\LaTeX$ in Tag Editor.

Tags: discussion, bug, formatting, display-math-mode

Problem: I can't write matrices and newlines with MathJax in $\LaTeX$ in the Tag Editor.

I've noticed on several SE pages that I can't write line breaks in MathJax. On some pages, an `x` is written instead of a `\\`. (see also [Bug: Writing multi-line formulas does not work in the "learn more" editor](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/767/22437))

E.G.

```
$$
\begin{align*}
r &= \left| z \right| = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\
\varphi &= \operatorname{arctan2}\left( y,\, x \right) = \arg\left( z \right)\\
x &= r \cdot \cos\left( \varphi \right)\\
y &= r \cdot \sin\left( \varphi \right)
\end{align*}
$$
```

looks like this:

[image]

Here on Math.SE just a line spacing is inserted.
Of course you can simply start a new alignment for each line break, but that doesn't work for vectors, matrices, ..., which makes writing wikis for tags that only consist of them (e.g. [nil-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nil-geometry)) quite difficult.

E.G.

```
$$
q' = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

looks like

[image]

(Note: This code works outside of the tag editor (for me))

---

> You need to remove the dollar signs before and after. The matrix and align environments don't need dollar signs. – Paramanand Singh

Even when I write it like this it doesn't work:

[image]

Also, I actually always use align and it always works except in tag editor...

---

My Browser is Crome: Version $113.0.5672.127$ (Official Build) ($64$-Bit)

My divise is: A Laptop with:

Edition: Windows $140$ Pro

Version: $21$H$2$

Buiild: $19044.2965$

Power: Windows Feature Experience Pack $1000.19041.1000.0$

Comment: You need to remove the dollar signs before and after. The matrix and align environments don't need dollar signs.

Comment: By "tag editor" you mean editing tag-infos, right? Maybe the tags ([meta-tag:tag-wikis])  and/or ([meta-tag:mathjax]) would be suitable here.

Comment: It seems that there are tag-infos containing things such as [pmatrix](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1590908/tag-infos-wikis-and-excerpts-containing-the-given-word?word=pmatrix) or [align](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1590908/tag-infos-wikis-and-excerpts-containing-the-given-word?word=align). 
When I checked some of them, they seem to be displayed correctly - for example, [matrix-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/matrix-equations/info) or [hausdorff-distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/hausdorff-distance/info).

Comment: Did you try to submit such an edit? It is possible that only the preview is faulty - I do not know whether the bug report here was actually corrected at some point: [MathJax bug in tag wiki edit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28322).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - Does that in fact fix it? I've learned that the dollar signs are unnecessary with begin/end, but I used both (for "align") for the longest time, and it worked.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes. I mean editing tag-infos. I didn't try to submit this.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the tip, but even when I write it like this it doesn't work:
 [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mypvg.png)

Comment: @KevinDietrich Do you have example of a text that you wanted to add to some specific tag wiki? Somebody with full editing rights might then try to edit that wiki to see what the final result looks like. (But as I said above, I suspect the issue is only with the preview.)

Comment: Interestingly, when I try the same thing, the preview looks differently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Rsb.png (I did not submit the edit, since I do not have the full text of the wiki for that tag.)